# How to remove Debian packages which does not belong to current Debian version repository

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I try to cleanup a Debian system on which several packages are installed after multiple Debian upgrades, which belongs to different Debian versions.

I.e. on a Debian Bullseye system, there are:

- libsodium18 (Stretch only)
- libsodium23 (Buster and Bullseye)

installed ([libsodium](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libsodium)).

Now, I do not need libsodium18 and want to remove it.

How can I automatically remove such packages, which do not exist anymore on the current installed Debian (Bullseye) system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `aptitude`, which supports searching for “obsolete” packages (*i.e.* packages which aren’t available from the configured repositories).

```
aptitude search '~o'
```

will list all such packages, and

```
sudo aptitude purge '~o'
```

will purge them (after telling you what it’s about to do and asking for confirmation).

If you don’t have `aptitude`, you’ll need to install it first:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Comment: You can use apt-get install --reinstall packagename to verify that the package cannot be found anywhere anymore.